# Array with object keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I create an array with keys as objects (instances of a class)?

I am trying to do something like:

```
const parent = {};

while (child !== undefined) {
    for (const element of list) {
        parent[element] = child;
    }
    child = child.next;
}
```

This is basically the idea; the code works if element is a string, but it doesn't work correctly if the element is an object.

Comment: What do you mean by "not VARIABLES"?

Comment: I edited it. I mean objects (instances of class that I have created)

Comment: Not variables with types like String, int, etc

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous. You should probably try using examples and desired answers to explain clearly what are you struggling with.

Comment: Declare parent as an array and not an object. var Parent = new Array();

Comment: So basically, I am trying to build an array- whose keys are objects- dynamically, but it does not work with objects as keys.

Comment: Ok, I will try that

Comment: @PiyushKhanna use `[]` not `new Array()`

Comment: Still does not work. It only works when keys are Strings or integers, but not objects

Comment: You cannot use an object for a property name. A property value, yes, but not the name.

Comment: Hamman, just to be clear, arrays can only have numeric indices. What you are really doing is creating an object with properties... I know PHP calls that an associative array, but in javascript, there is no such thing.

Comment: Can you use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in the environment where you run your code? Because `Map` does support any object as key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in an ES2015 Environment you can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

It would look like this:

```
let parent = new Map();
while (child !== undefined) {
    for (const element of list) {
        parent.set(element, child);
    }
    child = child.next;
}
```

You can run the below proof in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/shoj/pen/mBpygV?editors=1012)

```
let parent = new Map();
const KEY1 = {};
parent.set(KEY1, 'hello');
console.log(parent.get(KEY1)); // hello

const KEY2 = {};
parent.set(KEY2, 'world');
console.log(parent.get(KEY2));

parent.set('est', {a: 'a'});
console.log(parent.get('est'));
```

Or see it in action as a stack snippet

```js
(function($) {
  const ELEMENTS = {
    $h1: $('#hello'),
    $container: $('#container')
  };
  let parent = new Map();
  const KEY1 = {};
  parent.set(KEY1, 'hello');
  console.log(parent.get(KEY1)); // hello

  const KEY2 = {};
  parent.set(KEY2, 'world');
  console.log(parent.get(KEY2));

  parent.set('est', {
    a: 'a'
  });
  console.log(parent.get('est'));


  /** original code from question w Map  **/
  var list = []; // to prevent error
  let parenta = new Map();
  let child;
  while (child !== undefined) {
    for (const element of list) {
      parenta.set(element, child);
    }
    child = child.next;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="hello"></h1>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I am using ES2015 Environment. I will try using a map

Comment: Josh Bowling, great answer. I took the liberty of embedding the codepen as a stack snippet.

Comment: Thanks! I'll consider using these in the future as well

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `.toString()` is called on anything passed to an object as a key before it's used as a key. This is part of the Javascript language specification.

You can however make [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) object keys if you want, but Symbols only take strings as a parameter.

Comment: You could use a `Map`

Answer (score 0):

This does not work as the method `toString()` will be called return something like `[object Object]` for all the items.

Property names can only be strings, but they can be any string... You could just turn the object into a string, using `JSON.stringify(element)` but you won't be able to use the key value like the object, since it will only be a representation of it...

Another solution (maybe better?) is to have a function on your class that create a string representation of the object... Let's say your object is coming from the database, you could use the record ID. You could use some random string too for what it is worth.

I'd be able to give you a better solution if I knew why you want to store the object as the key to start with.

Comment: I need to find the shortest path between two vertices using BFS. So, what I try to implement is having each vertex's parent using BFS, and then find the shortest path through: parent[destination], parent[parent[destination]], ...etc until I reach the source vertex.

Comment: Note that vertex is an object, so destination and source are objects from type Vertex

Comment: a simple ID could work then... But I think you should rethink your class to provide a better way to do it.